# In Visual Basic, I keep getting String To double Error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a length check in my  coffee shop program...
i have sorted some of it out but i cant see where I am going wrong.

```
Dim Name As String

MsgBox("Welcome. You Are On The 'Hot Mornings' Self-Ordering Service", vbInformation, "Welcome To Hot Mornings!")
        Name = InputBox("Please Enter Your Name", "Welcome To Hot Mornings!", ,     MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)

If Len(Name <= 3) Then
        Do Until Len(Name > 3)
            MsgBox("Error!", vbExclamation, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
            MsgBox("An Error Occureed Earlier. We Are Currently Trying To fix This     Issue.", vbInformation, "Error!")
            Name = InputBox("Please Enter Your Name.", , "Must Contain More Than 3     Characters", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: _What does the error say?_

Answer (score 3):

```
Len(Name <= 3)
```

This code doesn't make any sense.

You're checking whether `Name` (a string) is less or equal to than 3 (huh?), then getting the `Len()` of the result of that check.  (huh?)

You probably want to get the `Len()` of the string (`Len(Name)`), then check whether the result of that (which is a number) is less than or equal to 3.

Comment: +1. Yes, he probably meant Len(Name) <= 3, but even then I would recommend using `Name.Length <= 3`, to keep it more .NET-ish.