# Boolean is two bytes in .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory-management, boolean

This question originates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14425449/897326). I tried this statement in VS to see what happens:

```
Len(Name <= 3)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204256/why-does-boolean-consume-more-memory-than-char) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294905/why-in-net-system-boolean-takes-4-byte), Boolean should consume 4 bytes. According to MSDN, [Len Function in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Returns an integer containing either the number of characters in a
>   string or the nominal number of bytes required to store a variable.

`Name <= 3` should convert 3 to String and perform string comparison, returning a boolean value, so `Len` should evaluate number of bytes in it, which should be 4. For some reason, above code returns 2, regardless of the second parameter. In other words, `Len(True)` also returns 2. Tried for different platform targets (32 and 64) - same thing.

**Why does `Len(Boolean)` return 2 instead of 4?**

Comment: As the answers you linked to say: boolean can sometimes use 4 bytes in .Net, but not always. For example, in an array of booleans, each one will take 1 byte.

Comment: @svick: Is there any condition when it would take 2 bytes? Is there any official information on how many bytes are taken when?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> With user-defined types and Object variables, the Len function returns the size as it will be written to the file by the FilePut function. If an Object contains a String, it will return the length of the string. If an Object contains any other type, it will return the size of the object as it will be written to the file by the FilePut function.

Len() is a legacy function, it should only be used in code that was ported from previous generation Visual Basic projects.  Where it would typically appear in code that involved binary serialization of VB values.  Sizes of basic types were different in those old versions.  `Integer` was 16 bits for example, explaining the great number of bad pinvoke declarations you find in the web that use Long.  And `Boolean` was a VARIANT_BOOL under the hood, a 16-bit value.  Furthermore quirky by having its `True` value convert to -1 instead 1.

Clearly adopting the .NET sizes would have been a heavily breaking change to a lot of data that exists in files written by a VB6 program.  Or binary data sent across a TCP connection.  Etcetera.  Accordingly, the Len() function returns the legacy sizes.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN's [Data Type Summary (VS2012)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the size of Boolean is dependent on the implementing platform. However if you look at [the same page for VS2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) it does say that Boolean is 2 bytes.

ECMA-335 section III.1.1.1 states:

> The evaluation stack only holds 4- or 8-byte integers, but other
>   locations (arguments, local variables, statics, array elements, fields) can hold 1 - or
>   2-byte integers. For the purpose of stack operations the bool (§III.1.1.2) and char
>   types are treated as unsigned 1-byte and 2-byte integers respectively. Loading from
>   these locations onto the stack converts them to 4-byte values

And section III.1.1.2 states:

> A CLI Boolean type occupies 1 byte in memory. A bit pattern of all zeroes denotes a value of false. A bit pattern with any one or more bits set (analogous to a non-zero integer) denotes a value of true. For the purpose of stack operations boolean values are treated as unsigned 1-byte integers

---

So given that, I feel only more confused as to why you get 2 and not 1